# Dealing with numerical cycles and sub-cycles in supervised neural network learning

Tags: machine-learning

I'm working on hobby project trying to identify trading opportunities in the FOREX using an MLP. I do not treat this a time series per se, rather I just collect a lot of stats on the local environment on a minute-by-minute basis to predict the market position at time + x, where x is something I need to adjust to see how ambitious I can be projecting forwards.

Some factors I want to collect are day of the week and time of day, which I know to have an impact on trading activity. Time has been relatively simple; I break it down into an x-y Cartesian graph and treat is as two variables, making a square around the origin at a 45 degree angle... now it can be treated as continuous and x and y always have a distinct pair value. The day of the week, however, is causing some problems in that it is parsed as being a value between 0, and 6 and that does not break down nicely into a cycle when daily time has already been defined as its own cycle. Especially in the case of high trading on day 0 (or 1 if I choose to add 1 to everything) as it would inflate all weights for subsequent days, which might not actually be as important.

I'm not sure I can normalise around the middle of the week because there can be high activity at the opening and closing of the markets, which are now polar opposites through normalisation. The daily cycles are more important and predictable because companies repatriate foreign earnings at roughly the same time, but both are important. I'm getting few false positives, but plenty of false negatives (in a way, that is. Market movement predicted as ~zero when it actually moves a lot) and day-of-the-week is surely at least one factor in this.

At this point it seems like I would need to produce 6 discrete models, one for each day (no trading on Saturday), which seems excessive. I feel this question is a split between stats and SO so not sure where to post; this must surely crop up in practical situations such as predicting employee absenteeism or work-related accidents and a whole host of other things. I'm curious if there is an established way to deal with numerical cycles and sub-cycles where they are incorporated complementarily – does anyone know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stats is definitely more suitable - on SO such kind of questions are off-topic. But even for stats, you still need to include more details, instead of a vague natural-language description of your problem. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: @BartoszKP knew I took a risk :) But I have seen some very knowledgeable people visit the machine learning tag and I think the problem is at least interesting and across all programming languages. I've answered similar problems to this myself on SO, so I hold out hope that it gets some attention :)